# How to create a property that is an "object" javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to create a game object class that contains a sprite object. I think I'm misunderstanding something fundamental. 
edit: The sprite class works but the gameObj class does not.

```
function sprite(img) {
    this.image = img;
    this.w = img.width; 
     this.h = img.height;
}
function gameObj(img, x, y) {
    var sp = sprite(img); 
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
var aCircle = new sprite(circle); 
var aGround = new gameObj(ground, 400,700);
```

Comment: "The sprite class works but the gameObj class does not" — Define "works", what do you expect to happen? How does that differ from what actually happens?

Comment: this is just a portion of the code. Later I'm using this method to draw it. When I call the sprite.draw function from aCircle it works, but not from aGround. 

gameObj.prototype.draw = function() {
    this.sp.draw(this.x, this.y);
}

Comment: Do you see a difference between `var aCircle = new sprite(circle);` and `var sp = sprite(img);` ?

Comment: Though the language does not require it, there is a pretty standard convention of naming `constructor functions` with a capital letter, to remind the coder that the `new` keyword is needed.

Answer (score 1):

To call a function as a constructor, use the `new` keyword.

```
var sp = new sprite(img);
```

This will make `this` (inside that function) refer to "a new object" and not the normal context (`window` since you haven't specified another context).

Convention dictations that constructor functions be capitalised though (`Sprite`).

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `new` keyword in the gameObj constructor :

```
var sp = new sprite(img);
```